# firstOrFail returning the wrong record from Eloquent Query Builder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a table in my databases called `tallies` that keeps track of the `count` for particular entities. The two key fields in the table are:

- **type**: the name of the entity
- **count**: the count of the entity

Right now in the table I have two records, the **first** record has a type of `hardDrives` and the **second** has a type of `monitors`.

I have a method in my repository used for incrementing the count for a particular record in a `tallies` table:

```
public function decreaseCountBy($type, $number){

    $countCollection = $this->tally->where('type', '=', $type )->firstOrFail();

    $record = $countCollection->first();

    // Troubleshooting output
    die(var_dump([$type, $record->toArray()]));

    // The rest of the method
    $record->count -= $number;
    $result = $record->save();
    if(!$result){
        throw new \Exception('Error saving decrementation');
    }
    return $record->count;
}
```

When I send the request to increment `monitors` and look at the output of the troubleshooting die and dump in this method and get the following output:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string 'monitors' (length=8)
  1 => 
    array (size=5)
      'id' => int 4
      'type' => string 'hardDrives' (length=10)
      'count' => int 15
      'created_at' => string '2014-12-21 03:50:04' (length=19)
      'updated_at' => string '2014-12-21 14:35:28' (length=19)
```

Even though I'm using `monitors` as the value for `$type` in the query, I get the record for `hardDrives`.

After this, I tried changing the method to fire the query:

```
$countCollection = $this->tally->where('type', $type )->get();
```

And then I get the correct result:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string 'monitors' (length=8)
  1 => 
    array (size=5)
      'id' => int 5
      'type' => string 'monitors' (length=8)
      'count' => int 3
      'created_at' => string '2014-12-21 03:50:04' (length=19)
      'updated_at' => string '2014-12-21 03:50:04' (length=19)
```

I could stop here and add in my own exception throw if there is an error finding the record, but when I read the [API Documentation](http://laravel.com/api/4.2/) for the Builder class' method `firstOrFail()` (sorry I can't link directly to it), the method is described as:

> Execute the query and get the first result or throw an exception.

I'd like to use the built in Laravel Exception that get's thrown when the records is not found rather than using my own.

Is there something I'm missing here? When I look for other examples in the laravel [Eloquent](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent) documentation it looks like I'm building the query correctly.

More than anything else I'd like to know *why* it's failing rather than just a work around.

**Resolution**

Here's the final version of the method just to show everyone how it ended up:

```
public function decreaseCountBy($type, $number){
    $record = $this->tally->where('type', '=', $type )->firstOrFail();
    $record->count -= $number;
    $result = $record->save();
    if(!$result){
        throw new \Exception('Error saving decrementation');
    }
    return $record->count;
}
```

Normally when you perform a `->get();` to retrieve the data, the result is an eloquent `Collection` instance holding multiple records. From there if you wanted to retrieve only the first record you could use the `->first()` method of the Collection class to get an eloquent `Model` class instance with that record's information.

In the case of `firstOrFail()`, what you're telling the query builder is that you only want the first record if found. Because you will only ever receive one record's worth of data, eloquent skips the collection and returns a model instance.

In my code above I've removed the line that "grabs the model of the first record", i.e. `$record = $countCollection->first();`, and renamed the variables to fit the expected results better, i.e. `$record` in place of `$countCollection`.

Comment: Not sure if this is causes the problem but you definitely don't need to call `first()` after using `firstOrFail()`. `firstOrFail()` already returns a single model and not a collection

Comment: That must have been it. When I removed the `first()` from the record grab it worked. It makes sense too, if I was calling first on a single `tallies` model instance it's like saying 'hey, give me the record I found and then give me the first record in the table'. If you want to submit the answer I'll give you the check.

Comment: Alright. Sure, will do :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to call `first()` after you already have called `firstOrFail()`. firstOrFail() already returns a single model and not a collection and calling `first()` on a model triggers a completely new select statement (this time without the `where`)

As @Jarek Tkaczyk pointed out below, with your code, two queries would run against the DB

1. `select * from tallies where type = ?`
2. `select * from tallies`

This means in your case the result of the first query gets overwritten by the second one.

#### Some background information

`firstOrFail()` does nothing else than calling `first()` and then throwing an exception if `first()` returns `null`

```
public function firstOrFail($columns = array('*'))
{
    if ( ! is_null($model = $this->first($columns))) return $model;

    throw (new ModelNotFoundException)->setModel(get_class($this->model));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the extra detail.

Comment: It's not that calling `first` again doesn't make sense. It returns completely different result in fact. Under the hood there are 2 db queries: `select * from tallies where type = ?` and then `select * from tallies` called on the model returned from the 1st query.

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk Ooops you're right. I ignored the `__call` in the model class which creates a new query and therefore runs a new select statement. I'm gonna update the answer accordingly. Thanks for pointing it out.